# Uninstall MySql on OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, uninstall

I accidentally installed the binary package of MySql on my Mac OS X.

Now I don't see anything about MySql. How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found [this series of commands](http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard). Actually I don't like this kind of hacking, but it seams to remove MySQL successfully.

To uninstall MySQL and completely remove it (including all databases) from your Mac do the following:

> Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!   Stop the
>   database server
>
> ```
> sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
> sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
> sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
> ```
>
> Edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`
>
> ```
> rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
> sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
> ```

I was able to install XAMPP afterwards and start this MySql installation without problems.

Comment: 3rd time this week I've had to do this, Mavericks on retina keeps locking up >:-(